# C++ - segmentation fault when using vectors

Tags: c++, vector

i was working on a problem from LeetCode about finding intersection elements in two different arrays.

and when i pass the input it throws a segmentation fault.

here is my solution (the solve() function only):

```
vector<int> solve(){
    int n,m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector<int> arr1, arr2;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> arr1[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        cin >> arr2[i];
    }
    sort(arr1.begin(), arr1.end());
    sort(arr2.begin(), arr2.end());

    vector<int> result;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < n && j < m){
        if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]){
            result.push_back(arr1[i]);
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else if(arr1[i] > arr2[j]){
            j++;
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: When you set an entry in a vector, you must make sure it is current that size. You can resize the vector using the `resize` function.

Comment: `cin >> arr1[i];` , here `arr1` is of size 0, you should use `pushback`.

Comment: `cin >> arr1[i];` --> `cin >> arr1.at(i);` -- That should explain the issue to you when you get a `std::out_of_range` exception instead of a seg fault.

Comment: *i was working on a problem from LeetCode about finding intersection elements in two different arrays.* -- Leetcode and similar sites are not designed to teach C++.  The questions there are designed for *experienced* programmers who have spare time solving random puzzles.  They assume that the language you choose to write the solution in, you know it well-enough to never make mistakes as you're making now, or ask basic questions about the chosen language.  If you want to learn C++, invest in peer-reviewed C++ books, and leave the puzzle sites alone, until you have a grasp of the language.

Comment: Why did you not step through the code with a debugger? It would show you exactly what you needed to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your vectors, `arr1` and `arr2` start off with a length of `0` each. When you try to set a certain index of them, this assumes that the index is already allocated, meaning the vector is long enough to contain that index, which it doesn't in your code.

To solve this, the best solution would be to simply call `push_back` instead of indexing the vector. This works because `push_back` will allocate more memory if needed.

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    arr1.push_back(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments mentioned, your vectors, as constructed have zero elements.  So accessing any element like arr1[i] is an error.

You can either construct your vectors with a specific size or you can use push_back to insert an element at the end.